# Cacti dskIndex RHEL

Tags: linux, monitoring, snmp, redhat, cacti

I'm attempting to use includeAllDisks in my snmpd.conf for RHEL 4 and RHEL 5 machines, but no data is being returned on the Cacti Data Query.

snmpwalk isn't giving me any results.

```
$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c public  172.19.4.140 .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.1 UCD-SNMP-MIB::dskIndex = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID
```

If I add

```
disk /
```

to snmpd.conf snmpwalk gives me the right results.

```
$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c public  172.19.4.140 .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.9.1.1
UCD-SNMP-MIB::dskIndex.1 = INTEGER: 1
```

I am wanting to deploy this to many systems using the same snmpd.conf (via Satellite). The disk configuration varies among systems and manually configuring snmpd.conf is not an optimal solution.

Is there a way to get includeAllDisks to work?

My snmpd.conf file:

```
rocommunity public <cacti server IP>
dontPrintUnits true
includeAllDisks
```

Answer (score 0):

includeAllDisks is pretty "new" directive. Better check whether your versin of snmp supports this at all.